# Rails 4.2 upgrade - No route matches [GET] "/assets/my_custom_scss_files.self.css"

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, rails-assets

I just upgraded to rails 4.2, and I'm finding that some asset errors are popping up (only in production).

These involve custom CSS files and javascript files that I had created and normal ones.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application.self.css")
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/my_css.self.css")
```

The corresponding file is in `production.rb` as:

```
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  config.assets.precompile += %w( my_css.css ... more custom css ... devise/sessions.css devise/sessions.js devise/passwords.js devise/passwords.css devise/confirmations.js devise/confirmations.css)
```

With the exception of `application.css`

All of them suddenly have the `.self.` before the `.css` which didn't used to be there.

It's only the precompiled `css` not the `js`.